# Windsor register singleton component for multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I want to register one class with 2 interfaces in Castle.Windsor.

does this code work... Will I have only one instance for both interfaces...

```
Component.For<IEnvironment>().ImplementedBy<OutlookEnvironment>().LifestyleSingleton()
Component.For<IOutlookEnvironment>().ImplementedBy<OutlookEnvironment>().LifestyleSingleton()
```

I need to double check this because my environment should always be the same instance...

So when I resolve using the IEnvironment interface I should get the same instance as when using IOutlookEnvironment to resolve the component

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to use the use multi-generic-parameter overload of the `Component.For` method

```
Component.For<IEnvironment, IOutlookEnvironment>()
         .ImplementedBy<OutlookEnvironment>()
         .LifestyleSingleton()
```

See also in the documentation: [Registering component with multiple services](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-one-by-one.md) section.